# What is the APEv1 tag identifier?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I've been cleaning up my MP3 collection and mass deleted all the ID3v1.x/ID3v2.x tags from my collection using taglib-sharp so I can use one program to re-tag them automatically. Anyway, I need to be able to remove APEv1 and APEv2 tags if their are any in the files. They're rarely used with MP3 but can be.

I need to know what the tag identifier is for APEv1, which is located at the end of the file. I've searched the web and found nothing.

As a side note, with APEv2, the tag identifier is 'APETAGEX' and is located at the beginning of the file.

Thanks.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/APE_tag

Answer (score 1):

According to the [APEv1 spec](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=APEv1_specification), the only difference between APEv1 and APEv2 is that APEv1 doesn't have a header and as such must always be at the end of a file or immediately before the ID3v1 tag.

The footer/header is 32 bytes long and starts with `APETAGEX`, so checking for the presence of an APE tag at the end of a file would involve reading 8 bytes at `Length - 32` and checking for that ASCII string, or `Length - 32 - 128` if there's an ID3v1 tag (or an entirely different position if there are footer APEv2 and ID3v2 tags in the file since there's really no strict precedent in that case).

That said, taglib-sharp should be able to remove footer APEv1 tags with `file.RemoveTags(TagTypes.Ape)`

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I assumed taglib would handle it but I wasn't totally sure. Thanks for the great info. +1

Comment: @NeilSiegfried If this worked for you, can you upvote/accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

According to [APE tag - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APE_tag) there is no actual tag, but the data is appended to the end of the file.

> APEv1
>
> The APEv1 tag was designed for the Monkey's Audio
>   format.[2] In MP3 files, the APE tag is stored at the very end of the
>   file, with no inline declaration in the body of the file. The software
>   handles the writing and access to the tag and does not interfere with
>   the contents of the MP3.